# How can I use custom Pyspark in Amazon Glue to read netCDF data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am creating a data pipeline to read NetCDF data in S3 and planning to use Amazon Glue for ETL with custom PySpark.

Is there any specific pyspark libraries that I can use which supports netCDF manipulation on data stored in S3.

Reference dataset would be like:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/publicsector/accessing-noaas-goes-r-series-satellite-weather-imagery-data-on-aws/?fbclid=IwAR3K_TS89Yolra5IKltINsI8NcPf8dk9FgF2X_iRBNVBIBQxqAZOXPi8jkY

Answer (score 0):

There is no inherent support for reading NetCDF data on [Glue](https://github.com/glue-viz/glue/issues/1735), you may have to use pure [spark implementation](https://github.com/geotrellis/geotrellis-netcdf).